# Casting Action<string> to Action<object>

Tags: c#, delegates

I need to cast an `Action<string>` to `Action<object>`. While this is type-unsafe in general, in my case it will always be called with a string. I'm getting this error:

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Action1[System.String]' to type 'System.Action1[System.Object]'.`

Any clues? Reflection is fair game. Wrapping the one delegate into another **is not**.

UPDATE:
I created a new question at [Creating an performant open delegate for an property setter or getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085798/creating-an-performant-open-delegate-for-an-property-setter-or-getter) with a better explanation of my issue, and a solution using wrapping which I want to improve on

Comment: Sorry, but the CLR just doesn't have a way to do this without wrapping one delegate with another.

Comment: It may be helpful to include why you are trying to do this (working with 3rd party library, curiosity, etc.) because as Gabe mentions, this is impossible without wrapping it in another delegate. It is possible however that there is a solution to an underlying problem you may be having.

Comment: Any particular reason for opposing wrapping the delegate with other.. its very straight forward than reflection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your post specifies that wrapping in another delegate is not an option but unfortunately that's really your best choice here.  The CLR simply does not allow for a cast between delegates in this direction.  No amount of reflection can fix this either.  Can you elaborate further on why this is not an option?

The reason why is that it creates type safety issues because the caller can pass any object into the `Action<object>` while the `Action<string>` can only handle strings.  Even if your code only passes in a `string` the CLR cannot guarantee this and hence does not allow for the unsafe conversion.

The next best option I can think of is change the original method which is being wrapped in a `Action<string>` from taking a parameter of type `string` to one that takes `object`.  Then let it manually verify the type is `string`.  For example

```
// Original Version
void Method(string str) {
  // Operate on the string
}

// Modified version
void Method(object obj) { 
  string str = (string)obj;
  // operate on the string
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, it's not safe.  Something that can accept any string can't (necessarily) accept any object.  Think of a example method:

```
void method(String s)
{
  s.Trim();
}
```

Obviously, this would fail if s were an object without `Trim`.

Technically, this means `Action` is contravariant on T.  You could assign an `Action<string>` to a hypothetical `Action<SubclassString>` reference, but `string` can not be subclassed.

It's true that C# allows regular unsafe casts (e.g. `object` itself to `string`), at the risk of a `InvalidCastException`.  However, they chose not to implement the infrastructure for unsafe delegate casts.

EDIT: I don't know of a way to do it without a wrapper.

Comment: Off course. I added a clarification to the question. My contract ensures that it will only be called with a string. So casting is indeed what I need.

Comment: Can a moderator delet this answer? It does not help me and might stop other people from looking at the question.

Comment: @David, when I answered the question, it said, "I need to cast an `Action<string>` to `Action<object>`. It stands to reason that it should be possible" and I explained why this is wrong.  Even now, the title of the question is unclear.

Comment: @Mathew, why is it unclear? What would be a clearer alternative?

Comment: An actual cast or assignment is impossible, and I explained why.  It's hard to give a good alternative, since you say wrappers are out.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late bump, but I was looking for a way to do this today and stumbled upon this post.  Really, the only simple way I found to do it was to wrap `Action<string>` within a new `Action<object>`.  In my case, I was pushing my Actions into a Concurrent Dictionary, and then retrieving them by type.

Effectively, I was processing a queue of messages where actions could be defined to handle messages with a particular typed input.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action<object>> _actions = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action<object>>();
Action<string> actionStr = s => Console.WriteLine(s);

var actionObj = new Action<object>(obj => { 
  var castObj = (V)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(V)); actionStr(castObj); 
} );

_actions.TryAdd(typeof(string), actionObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since reflection is fair game, I will suggest the following. You can get away from the casting problem if you keep track of an Object, MethodInfo, and possibly the parameter you will execute against. An example of how the concept works is as follows:

```
Action<string> s;
Action<object> o;

object sTarget = s.Target;
object oTarget = o.Target;

MethodInfo sMethod = s.Method;
MethodInfo oMethod = o.Method;

// Time to invoke in a later time.
sMethod.Invoke(sTarget, new object[] { strVal });
oMethod.Invoke(oTarget, new object[] { objVal });
```

The only danger with this is the possibility that the wrong parameter type will be executed against the wrong method. You might need to do some bookkeeping here to prevent this. But, in your case, since there is a guarantee that a string is going to be passed (and since a string is always an object), this should always succeed.